# ClassNotFoundException when running a Spring + Maven2 project on Tomcat 6 from within Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven-2, m2eclipse

When trying to launch a Web project from within Eclipse I get:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Project started to fail when I switched to Fedora 12 x64. The project worked on WinXP with same configuration.

Googling around I found posts claiming that going to *Project Properties -> Java EE Module Dependencies* and checking the *Maven Dependencies* box fixes the issue. Sadly it didn't worked for me.

I'm using Spring 2.5.6, Maven2, Eclipse 3.5 (with the m2e 0.10.0 plugin), Tomcat 6 and Java 6 running on Fedora 12 x64.

Has anyone seen this problem?

In case it helps here is my .classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="target/generated-sources/gpb"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>

    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>

    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.iam.jdt.core.mavenClasspathContainer">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**Update:** I don't have any problems building or running the project outside Eclipse.

Comment: Just a guess: could it be becuase org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER and org.eclipse.iam.jdt.core.mavenClasspathContainer conflict in some way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You seem to have both [Eclipse IAM](http://www.eclipse.org/iam/) and [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) stuff in your `.classpath`. I would do some cleanup:

- Use only one of these plugin (I suggest using M2Eclipse).
- Delete your project from Eclipse's workspace, delete the `.classpath` and `.project` and Import the project as a Maven project again.

**Update:** To get WTP support with M2Eclipse, you need to install the **Maven Integration for WTP** from the m2eclipse Extras update site: http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/ as illustrated below:

[image]

Comment: @pascalthivent, It seems that I was using Eclipse IAM before the switch without noticing. Anyway, did what you suggested, but now the project is not seen by Eclipse like a Web App. So now I don't even have the *Run As -> Run on Server* option.

Comment: @Elliot That's because you didn't install the Maven Integration for WTP when you installed M2Eclipse. I'll update my answer to cover this.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, that last info solved my problem. I removed the project, installed the integration for WTP and imported the project again. Only detail was that I had to disable the Maven plugin, build the project in a terminal and then enable the plugin again. Everything is working smoothly now. One thought, it seems to me that Eclipse is really lagging behind NetBeans on Maven support. I feel more productive in Eclipse, but cannot afford to lose time with things like this in my workplace. I think Eclipse's image is tarnished by the current state of the Maven plugins.

Comment: @Elliot Glad it's solved. I can understand your perception after a problem like this one even if it was more a user issue at the end (if I may). Personally, I find that Eclipse has very decent Maven support with M2Eclipse now, but feedback from others is always interesting.

Comment: @Pascal The m2eclipse docs could at least have a note saying "if you are planning on using WTP you better install the WTP integration from the extras repo". This means the first time I setup this project on WinXP I got it right by sheer luck. Which is really bad because I was fooled into thinking I mastered Maven projects in Eclipse (as you could see I didn't). Now if it weren't for SO I would have to decide between spending more time solving the issue or moving to NetBeans where my co-workers haven't had a problem yet. Guess what would have won..

Thanks for your help and SO rocks!.

Comment: @Elliot Ok, I get your point now and I have to agree on it (there is a bit of *documentation* at the bottom of http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html but this is indeed far from obvious).

Comment: @Pascal I had the same problem and installing the "Maven Integration for WTP" saved my bacon

Answer (score 9):

I had the same symptom with a different cause. I had to edit my .classpath file. The maven entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

...was lacking the attributes tag shown here. When I added the attributes tag the problem went away. I'm very curious how to configure that in the eclipse ui.

Comment: yep...   that definitively changed the error message so something application related... I guess it was a move in the right direction

Comment: ah thank you this worked for me, just added <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/> and its ok now

Answer (score 4):

Note that the steps to install the WTP integration have changed.

See:  [Maven/Tomcat Projects In Eclipse Indigo/3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356421/maven-tomcat-projects-in-eclipse-indigo-3-7)

Answer (score 1):

From time to time, face with same problem.

For some strange reason, this problem could be fixed this way

1) Right mouse click on project Maven -> Disable Maven Dependencies

2) Right mouse click on project Maven -> Enable Maven Dependencies

Comment: I do not have such options in Eclipse 3.7.2, did you mean `Disable Maven Nature`?