# NoClassDefFoundError when running Tomcat + Spring + Maven project (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven, noclassdeffounderror

What I get is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DB
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:446)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:430)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getAllDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:634)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:394)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:594)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

This class is inside maven jar (from M2 repository). I added Maven Dependencies to DeploymentAssembly (before I did it i got: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter). I use m2e plugin and have my project configured as Maven project. My app is deployed to standard location /.metadata/.plugins/.../tmp0. Inside of WEB-INF/lib I have all necessary jars. Project compiles with no error. What could I do wrong?

One quasi-solution is to add necessary libraries to Tomcat lib directory but I don't want to do that. I want to force Tomcat to use project libraries.

Comment: I think you're missing a lib which is not necessary at compile, but at runtime. Please check if you have the lib for mongodb in your WEB-INF/lib dir.

Comment: mongo-java.driver-2.5.2.jar that exists in .../tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/WEB-INF/lib contains com.mongo.DB class. That class is also needed at compile time. Is it possible that I need com.mongo.DB from another jar or another jar version? And when I add this jar to Tomcat lib directory it works fine (I get another missing class error)

Answer (score 6):

I have had a similar issue when trying to run the **mcv-ajax** and **mvc-basic** samples, distributed with **Spring 3** (both available at https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples - need an SVN client to download them, something like TortoiseSVN).

I was getting this ClassNotFoundException in my Tomcat6 startup log.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter characterEncodingFilter java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Feb 17, 2012 10:36:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Feb 17, 2012 10:36:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/mvc-basic] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I could run both Maven Clean and Maven Install goals, with no errors, and the project did not have any classpath errors.
I also installed the eclipse **Maven Integration for WTP** available under the **Maven Integration for Eclipse Extras** package, as instructed [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=classnotfoundexception:%20org.springframework.web.filter.characterencodingfilter&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFIQFjAC&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595315/classnotfoundexception-when-running-a-spring-maven2-project-on-tomcat-6-from-w&ei=rjg-T4aHO8P18QPw6_mGCA&usg=AFQjCNG0zzdguQV2t6yz9nGLHV5ipSEW7A), but still no luck...

The problem in my case, could be seen in the **Markers** tab in Eclipse, as a warning (yellow eclamation mark) with a description of **Classpath Dependency validator Message**
and an actual issue of **classpath entry org.eclipse.maven2_classpath.container will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.**

> To solve this issue

1. right-click on the problem description, and selected quick fix.
2. Select **Mark the associated raw classpath entry as a publish/export dependency**
3. Click on Finish
4. Do a **maven-clean** and a **maven-install**
5. right click on project, select run on server. Select Tomcat server to run on, and you should see the initial page.

> Conclusion
>   The steps described above, worked for me in making the project run successfully in my Eclispe Development Environment. Please give it a try to see if it will work for you.

An alternative solution which also seems to work, is

1. delete the project from eclipse, including all associated files in the workspace. (delete project directory from workspace as well)
2. Check the project out again from SVN into the workspace
3. Import new project in eclipse, but choose Maven\Existing Maven Project
4. Select the project from the disk and import.

Kind regards,

ta6hbe

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You didn't install the m2eclipse WTP integration.

If so, than this may me the source of wrong deployment. When WTP integration is installed You shouldn't need to change anythong in the deployment descriptor - the plugin should configure Your project automatically. If not, try RMB -> Maven -> Update project configuration, but be sure to install the WTP integration first.